# Is there a way to show vertical bar for each nav bar items?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to show each navbar items like the following

```
item1 | item2 | item3
```

How to display that vertical bar between items?

Comment: You need to post your code thats related to your question (HTML/CSS) and how do you plan on displaying this on viewports under 768px? What have you tried so far? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

When you style the navbars, do:

```
border-left: 1px solid #777;
border-right: 1px solid #777;
```